Use multiple fonts in the DataGridView in Visual Studio
I want to make dictionary so I used Visual Studio and DataGridView and linked it to access database so there are 2 rows. I want one to appear in a font called SANS and the other Tahoma.
I have tried to change the font in the DB but this does not work.

DataTrigger is an option, include code in your question to get the correct answer

Why would changing the font in the database have any effect? A font is about how text is displayed, so how it's displayed in your app has zero connection to how it's displayed in any particular database management app. Different management apps may display data from the same database using different fonts too. It would be only if the data actually contains the formatting information too, e.g. HTML that you can actually change it in the database itself, but there's no indication that that's what you're doing.

The grid itself has a DefaultCellStyle property of type DataGridViewCellStyle, which has a Font property. That will be inherited by each row by default. If you want to change the style of a row, you need to set the DefaultCellStyle for that row explicitly. Each cell in the row inherits its Style property from the row unless you set that explicitly.

In my opinion, having different row or cell fonts goes against good UI design, header row excepted.

You can handle the CellFormatting event of the DataGridView to apply different fonts.
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If Not IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value) Then
        If e.RowIndex = 0 Then
            e.CellStyle.Font = New Drawing.Font("Sans", 12, Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
        Else
            e.CellStyle.Font = New Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12, Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

